# How can I copy the contents of one worksheet to another using a formula, not VBA or manual copy/paste, and have it skip blank rows?

Tags: excel-2007

Using a formula in Worksheet B, I want to automatically copy only rows containing data from Worksheet A to Worksheet B.  The result should be all the data from worksheet A with no blank rows as shown below.

```
 WORKSHEET A
              A            B          C           D
 Row 1                  Worksheet A Title
 Row 2     Header A    Header B    Header C    Header D
 Row 3       31           32         33          34
 Row 4       41           42         43          44
 Row 5
 Row 6       61           62         63          64
 Row 7                        
 Row 8       81           82         83          84



 WORKSHEET B
              A            B          C           D
 Row 1                  Worksheet B Title
 Row 2     Header A    Header B    Header C    Header D
 Row 3       31           32         33          34
 Row 4       41           42         43          44
 Row 5       61           62         63          64
 Row 6       81           82         83          84
 Row 7                        
 Row 8
```

If possible (not a requirement), I'd like to be able to continue this process by copying non-blank rows from Worksheet C and adding them to the first available row in Worksheet B.

```
 WORKSHEET C
              A            B          C           D
 Row 1                  Worksheet C Title
 Row 2     Header A    Header B    Header C    Header D
 Row 3     
 Row 4       401         402         403         404
 Row 5       501         502         503         504
 Row 6       
 Row 7       701         702         703         704                 
 Row 8     



 WORKSHEET B UPDATED
              A            B          C           D
 Row 1                  Worksheet B Title
 Row 2     Header A    Header B    Header C    Header D
 Row 3       31           32         33          34
 Row 4       41           42         43          44
 Row 5       61           62         63          64
 Row 6       81           82         83          84
 Row 7      401          402        403         404                  
 Row 8      501          502        503         504
 Row 9      701          702        703         704
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

In **Sheet1**, cell **E2** enter:

```
1
```

In cell **E3** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A3:D3)<>0,MAX(E1:E2)+1,"")
```

and copy down.  We see:

[image]

*NOTE*  All the "good" rows are marked sequentially.

In **Sheet2**, cell **A2** enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$8,MATCH(ROWS(1:$1),Sheet1!$E$2:$E$8,0),0)
```

copy both down and across. In **Sheet2** we see:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To fix the **first** issue, replace:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A3:D3)<>0,MAX(E1:E2)+1,"")
```

with

```
=IF(COUNTA(A3:D3)<>0,MAX(E$1:E2)+1,"")
```

before the copy-down.

The **second** issue requires an adjustment to:

the **8** in the second sheet!

Comment: Thanki you Gary's Student.  I'll set it up and let you know.

Comment: I tried the equations and it worked exactly as you stated for the scenarios above.  However, I came across two issues.  When there are two or more blank lines together, the equation in column E of Sheet1 restarts the number sequence from 1.  Also, in Sheet2, if that equation is carried beyond row 6, it gives the result #N/A.  Would it be possible to use a count function to simply identify lines with data as "1", then set the equation in Sheet2 to use only lines with the value "1"?  Or something to that nature?